# calling a script from Binary in chroot mode,not working

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, snmp, net-snmp

Part of a program named =program.c

```
int memoryPercent()
{
    int memoryPercent=0;
    FILE *pipe1 = NULL;

    pipe1=popen("/home/jatin/scripts/memoryPercent.sh","r");

    if(!pipe1)
    {
        snmp_log(LOG_ERR,"popen failed in temp(),errno:%d\n",errno);
        return -1;
    }

    if( fscanf(pipe1,"%d",&memoryPercent) != 1) 
    {
        snmp_log(LOG_ERR,"fscanf failed in temp fun(),errno:\n");
        return -2;
    }

    pclose(pipe1);
    return memoryPercent;
}
```

above is my calling code /home/jatin/scripts/memoryPercent.sh
    on this location a scripts is given and it is returning a INTEGER value.

in UBUNTU 12.04 when I compile and execute this code it is running perfectly.

but in my VM-WARE

I have copied all the necessary dependencies at the location /var/snmp3 and  executing this binary with CHROOT the syntax is

```
/usr/sbin/chroot /var/snmp3/ /usr/local/bin/program
```

it is showing value  "-1" only !!
Can anyone tell me what I am missing ?

the script is at the same location in `/var/snmp3/home/jatin/scripts/memoryPercent.sh`
as well as `/home/jatin/scripts/memoryPercent.sh` in 775 mode....

Comment: What is the error message logged?

Comment: Did you tried chdir following with chroot in C?

Comment: Have you checked the log? What's the value of `errno`? You can use e.g. [`strerror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror) to get a descriptive text showing the error message.

Comment: Another point, I guess the script uses `#!/bin/sh`, is there a  `/var/snmp3/bin/sh` program?

Comment: to know the path to command sh: which sh. Say it is /bin/sh, did you try: pipe1=popen("/bin/sh /home/jatin/scripts/memoryPercent.sh","r"); The idea is to force running a shell to execute your script.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg & Bruno von Paris : thanks .. its working now...just want to know is it a safe way to execute the script ? I suppose to call 50-60 scripts every second in infinite for loop. please guide me/..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the script manually from a chrooted shell.

I think you are missing the shell used by memoryPercent.sh. Have you copied the shell to the chrooted environment?